# jslint expected ';' saw '}' for inline function

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am using setInterval function of javascript, which expects a inline function defined which will be executed periodically. Below is my code snippet,

```
setInterval(
    function(){_this.getView().setModel( new JSONModel(_this._getRecentRatingsModel()) , "recentRatings")},
    interval);
```

But I'm facing jslint violation for this, it complains saying

> Expected ';' saw '}'

Its expecting ';' after _getRecentRatingsModel()
But if i use ; there the syntax for setInterval will be broken.

Help me how I can bypass this jslint check.

Comment: Please pretend you care about the people you ask help from and **format your code**

Comment: "But if i use ; there the syntax for setInterval will be broken." - why do you think that? you are allowed to use `;` inside functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's expecting a `;` here:

```
setInterval(function(){
    _this.getView().setModel(
        new JSONModel(_this._getRecentRatingsModel()
    ) , "recentRatings"); // <-- here
}, interval);
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `;` after `"recentRatings")`. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

will ignore line, but first you should try to resolve issue adding ';' :)

Comment: I love the thought of adding 20+ characters to avoid adding 1 :p

Comment: hehe god point :) maybe he will have to ignore line in some other case, so now he know how to do that :D